# Importing .txt data into a matrix

Tags: import

I have the following .txt data:

```
 1               0               4               0
 2               0             3.5               0
 3             0.5               4               0
 4               1               4               0
```

I would like to import this data and store it in the following format:

```
A={{0,4,0},{0,3.5,0},{0.5,4,0},{1,4,0}}
```

How can I do that?

Comment: If i don't want to read the last column, how should i proced?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It looks like you don't want the first column. Using `Import`:

```
data = Import["path/to/file/data.txt", "Table"][[;; , 2 ;;]]

(*{{0, 4, 0}, {0, 3.5, 0}, {0.5, 4, 0}, {1, 4, 0}}*)
```

Comment: As an alternative `Part` notation, `[[All, 2;;]]` is a bit syntactic sugar, but might be easier to read/understand quickly.

Comment: @Marchi, if i don't want to read the last column, how should i proced?

Answer (score 3):

You can also use `ReadList` in a clever way for this, and since `ReadList` is a low level function, I always use it instead of `Import` especially for large files. Let's define what to omit from the result:

```
skip[_String] := Nothing (* use Sequence[] pre V. 10.2 *)
omit = skip[Word];
```

Now we can use `ReadList` directly:

```
ReadList["file.txt", {omit, Number, Number, Number}]

(* {{0, 4, 0}, {0, 3.5, 0}, {0.5, 4, 0}, {1, 4, 0}} *)
```

Or you can use it normally and do post-processing as the other answers show.

Answer (score 1):

To do it differently:

```
A = Transpose @ Drop[Transpose @ Import["name_of_file.txt", "Table"], 1]
```